# CRM 2013 script error Network Error 0x2eff

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using CRM 2013 OData services and I'm getting expected result but when I open javascript console on IE 10/11 under errors 
Script7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.

I'm not using jquery.

Please suggest

its on On-Premise, http, AD, Lead entity, in all browsers. I'm using Rest Odata SDK

```
var options = "$select=Telephone1&$filter=AccountId eq guid'" + regardingObjectId + "'";
    SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("Account", options, retrieveAccountsCallBack, errorCallBack, accountsRetrieveComplete);
```

Comment: The error message doesn't tell much about itself, lots more details are needed: Online/OnPremise ? http/https ? AD/IFD ? WebResource/Iframe ? Behavior on other browsers ? Relevant Code ?

Comment: So you're running the Javascript on the Lead entity form?  What's the URL (feel free to obfuscate the domain) you're attempting to hit vs the URL of the page?

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with using jQuery Ajax request.
And i found solution for my issue.
This is IE security restriction, you can set security goto Browser Property(Configuration) then security, then you can add site that you needed to intranet sites or you can switch internet security lower than normal(middle) mode, then restart all IE bookmarks and must work
(sorry if some menu items have other name that i wrote, i use localized version and i don't now it english name)